# Codeigniter Ajax JSON return not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view inside which I have a button on which after a click I would like to retrieve some data from the controller.

This is inside the view:

```
    <script>
    $('.ajaxBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajaxController',
            data: "",
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(response){ console.log(response); alert(response)}
        });
    });
</script>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ajaxController extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        echo json_encode("datafromajax");
    }


}
```

And I have a route defined like this:

```
$route['ajaxControl'] = "ajaxController/index";
```

However I have no response data even though the response is 200.

Thanks for any help

EDIT2// Loading a JSON from for an online source works fine

EDIT// Response:

> XHR Loaded (index - 200 OK - 39.48300000047311ms - 35.38KB) VM3852:3
>   http://davids-macbook-pro.local:5757/ajaxController/index VM3853:3
>   Object {startedDateTime: "2016-04-09T08:45:16.133Z", time:
>   39.48300000047311, request: Object, response: Object, cache: Object…}cache: Object__proto__: Object__defineGetter__:
>   **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: **lookupSetter**()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf:
>   isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable:
>   propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString:
>   toString()valueOf: valueOf()get **proto**: get **proto**()set
>   **proto**: set **proto**()connection: "122019"pageref: "page_7"request: ObjectbodySize: 0cookies: Array[2]headers:
>   Array[11]headersSize: 1099httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"method:
>   "POST"queryString: Array[0]url:
>   "http://davids-macbook-pro.local:5757/ajaxController/index"**proto**:
>   Objectresponse: Object_transferSize: 35380bodySize: 34973content:
>   Objectcookies: Array[0]headers: Array[10]headersSize: 407httpVersion:
>   "HTTP/1.1"redirectURL: ""status: 200statusText: "OK"**proto**:
>   ObjectstartedDateTime: "2016-04-09T08:45:16.133Z"time:
>   39.48300000047311timings: Object__proto__: Object

Comment: change url: 'ajaxController/index', or just defive Javascript variable like `var base_url=<?php echo base_url();?>` than change in your AJAX `URL:base_url+ajaxController/index''`

Comment: thanks now it's error free, could you please advise how to encode that recieved json in the success function?

Comment: echo json_encode($yourvalue); into your mathod

Comment: success : function(response){ $('#ajaxdiv').html(response); } is not working

Comment: try this console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: console.log(response) logs the whole response object with the headers and so on. I need only the string from the controller "datafromajax"

Comment: Can you post your response?@DavidN

Comment: Please open console on your browser and send us response. Probably your POST url is wrong. Try `<?php echo site_url('ajaxControl'); ?>`

Comment: response added to the main thread :) the thing is I'm not submitting anything yet, just pulling the data from the controller via ajax

Comment: the behaviour is the same via echo site_url

Comment: try $ab=array("asd"=>"datafromajax"); echo json_encode($ab);

Comment: no help, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Chnage the string to array in json_encode()

From `echo json_encode("datafromajax");` To  `echo json_encode(['data'=>"datafromajax"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define **base_url()**

eg.

```
$arr = array("str"=>"datafromajax");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And in the ajax function

```
url: <?php echo base_url();?> +'ajaxController'

 success : function(response){ console.log(response.str); alert(response.str)}
```

Comment: the response from the Controller is content-type=text/html even I explicitly set header('Content-Type', 'application/json'); in the controller

Comment: var formData = {};
$.post('http://davids-macbook-pro.local:5757/ajaxController/index', formData)
  .done (showResult)
  .fail(showError);